# How does solidity know the current tokenId if the transaction has yet to be picked up by miners?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

In the ERC721 OpenZeppelin contracts, the minting process goes like this:

- Get the current token ID `_tokenIds.current()`
- `_safeMint` the current token ID
- Some time passes while a miner picks up the transaction and establishes it to the chain

Let's say we're on token 100. If two people try to mint at the at the same time, wouldn't tokenIds.current() be 100 for both of them? And then `_safeMint` would be running with the same token IDs and one fails?

Clearly the scenario I'm outlining doesn't happen has hundreds of people try to mint projects at the same time without issue. I think I'm missing something about how tokenIds.current() works.

Answer (score 3):

> *If two people try to mint at the at the same time, wouldn't tokenIds.current() be 100 for both of them?*

All transactions within a block are executed in series - not in parallel. So the first one gets ID 100, and the second gets ID 101.

Comment: Thank you so much! Makes a lot more sense now. Does this mean it would be impossible to have a mint where a user gets to select the token ID they want to mint?

Comment: @user12457151 They can select. This specific implementation shown in the question uses sequential IDs, but the [ERC-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) standard allows for non-sequential IDs as well... So you could also implement a function invoking the `_safeMint()` with an arbitrary ID, and the subsequent `_mint()` function validates that token with this ID is not minted yet.

Comment: Got it. In this case where users are selecting an ID, it could be the case that two users select the same ID, hit mint, and one will be blocked and one will go through, but it will cost them both gas correct? Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: @user12457151 Correct... The "blocked" user only pays gas fees until the failed validation of the ID existence. Then the transaction stops executing and reverts.

Comment: I am dealing with this exact scenario and I am trying to find a solution for the second person to not pay unnecessary gas fees. Is it possible to keep a global variable in the smartcontract 'lastMintedTokenId' and have a require statement at the start of the mint() method like so: require(tokenId != lastMintedTokenId). the lastMintedTokenId will be set to the tokenId argument right before the actual _safeMint() is called inside the mint() method. Would this prevent the unnecessary gas fees of the second person? Thank you for any tips/help related to this!

Comment: @JoeriBultheel In this case, the sender still pays the base 21k gas fee for a transaction, plus any cost of executing the code (e.g. reading `lastMintedTokenId` from persistent storage) until the failed `require()` condition. Anything after the failed condition is not executed, and they are refunded the remaining ETH amount that was meant for gas fees for the rest of the function execution. So it is generally a good practice to put `require()` conditions at the beginning of your functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I am still confused. With my solution, will the second person pay less or the same amount of gas? Preventing the _safeMint() method to be called in this way should prevent some redundant gas paying right? Also, I think I should keep a global variable map with booleans 'startedMinted' for all tokens, because using one lastMintedTokenId variable will not work for the situation with 3 or more people minting at the same time: person1: tokenA, person2: tokenB, person3: tokenA. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I understand your answer better now. I guess what I want to know is this: The amount of gas paid for the _safeMint() method (which my solution would prevent in a redundant scenario) is significantly higher compared to the base gas fee you mentioned? Thnx

Comment: @JoeriBultheel With your solution, the user pays less gas compared to failing later - but the gas amount they pay for the failing transaction is still non-zero... To your second question. Generally speaking, `_safeMint()` alone usually costs few thousand gas units (exact cost depends on overrides in your contract, as well as the NFT receiver implementation if it's a contract), which is less than the 21k base fee. However the user always pays the 21k base fee - no matter if the transaction fails or succeeds - plus the cost of executing (up until the point it fails).

Comment: @PetrHejda thank you so much for explaining, it really helps me a lot. There's one thing I don't fully understand yet though. Isn't reading data from a smart-contract supposed to be free (no-gas)? Would there not be a way to have a free method (view) to check first if the wanted tokenId is 'already being minted' before going further to the actual _safeMint() method?

Comment: @JoeriBultheel It is free if you use the [eth_call](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_call) RPC method. You can invoke the call for example by explicitly stating `.call()` with an offchain framework (example in [web3js docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.5/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call)). Or some frameworks (such as `ethers.js`) implicitly invoke a call on Solidity `view` and `pure` functions... If you invoke the Solidity function using a transaction (not a call), you still pay gas fees for this transaction, even though it only reads data.